# Mysql create group_concat union

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 sub query

1:

```
(select group_concat(a.name) 
 from A a 
 where a.id = c.a_id) as name
```

2:

```
(select group_concat(a.name) 
 from A a 
 where a.id = b.a_id) as name
```

now i need to create a `union` on it means i need unique list of names as Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the `group_concat()` on the `union`:

```
(select group_concat(abc.name) 
 from ((select name from A a where a.id = c.a_id) 
       union
       (select name from A a where a.id = b.a_id)
      ) abc
)
```

But, alas, that won't work because of MySQL scoping rules -- you are going two levels deep.  So, one solution is `or`:

```
(select group_concat(abc.name) 
 from A a
 where a.id = c.a_id or a.id = b.a_id)
) abc
```

Sadly, performance will probably be lousy because the `or` typically prevents use of indexes.

Hmmm . . . One way you can get uniqueness and still use indexes might be simple concatenation:

```
concat_ws(',',
          (select group_concat(abc.name) 
           from A a
           where a.id = c.a_id 
          ),
          (select group_concat(abc.name) 
           from A a
           where a.id = c.a_id and a.id <> b.a_id
          )
         )
```

This isn't 100% foolproof (two different `a.id` rows could have the same name resulting in a duplicate).  But there are many circumstances where this will work and each subquery should take advantage of an index for the `id` match.

Comment: HI Gordon good morning. i am getting error in case of concat_ws

Comment: @BhushanUniyal . . . What kind of error?  Your question is tagged "mysql" and `concat_ws()` is a very MySQL function:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws.

Comment: can you please brief me what it means a.id <> b.a_id ?

Comment: @BhushanUniyal . . . In SQL, `<>` means "not equals".